# How to read the modified data from the TextBox where TextBox gets data from QueryString?

Tags: asp.net, query-string, aspbutton

I have a `TextBox` named `TextBoxValue` and a `Button` named `ButtonGetValue` that are located on an `ASP WebForm` named `DestinationPage.aspx`. What I am doing is that I am filling the `TextBox` with a value that I am passing to this page from the previous page using a `QueryString`. I am implementing that in the following way:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonCompute" runat="server" Text="Compute" OnClick="ButtonCompute_Click" ValidationGroup="ComputeGroup"/
```

> `ButtonCompute` is a `Button` located on `SourcePage.aspx`, and clicking it simply passed the data to `DestinationPage.aspx` from `SourcePage.aspx`. This is not the `Button` that I was talking about earlier.

Code in `SoucePage.aspx.cs`:

```
int valueForDestination = 10; 
Response.Redirect("~/DestinationPage.aspx?Value = + valueForDestination);
```

Code in `DestinationPage.aspx.cs`:

```
int valueFromQS = Request.QueryString["Value"];
TextBoxValue.Text = valueFromQS;

<asp:Button ID="ButtonGetValueValue" runat="server" Text="Get Value" onclick="ButtonGetValue_Click" />
```

Now, what I do here is, once the value is displayed in the `TextBoxValue`, change it to `100` from `10`. And then I click on `ButtonGetValue`. But instead of getting `100`; which is the updated value, I am getting `10`; which was the initial value. How can I get the updated value?

**EDIT 1.0**
I apologize for not mentioning clearly what I want to do with `ButtonGetValue`. This `Button` simply reads the value from the `TextBox` and prints the value on the screen.

I am working on `ASP.NET WebForms`.

Comment: Are you setting `TextBoxValue.Text = valueFromQS` in an `IsPostBack` check?

Comment: No. It is inside `if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)` and the `if condition` directly in `Page_Load()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want it to change to the QueryString value on every postback, you want to wrap it in a !IsPostBack

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["Value"] != null) 
    {
        TextBoxValue.Text = Request.QueryString["Value"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Also in your example code you are passing through 10 in the query string, and you are also saying the default value is 10, if you want it to be 100 then you need to pass 100 into the querystring on your button click event.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited my question based on what you are asking. I apologize for not mentioning that piece of information while posting the question. I am performing the edit (10 -> 100) after I have got the query string. What I am trying to imply is that, even if I change the value to 100, on clicking `ButtonGetValue`, I am getting 10 as the output, whereas, I wanted 100 as I had changed `10` to `100` in the `TextBox`. Hope this helps. Also, I think your solution should work. I am testing that.